# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I am getting the following error when I am importing StockTradingEnv. I cannot understand how to do away with it.

> from env.StockTradingEnv import StockTradingEnv

I even tried importing **urlparse** the following, but even that does not help

> from urllib.parse import urlparse

Background: I am using the tutorial here to learn how to make a reinforcement learning environment from [this blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-a-custom-openai-gym-environment-for-stock-trading-be532be3910e).

ERRoR

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-68b0ade668b4> in <module>
      7 from stable_baselines import PPO2
      8 
----> 9 from env.StockTradingEnv import StockTradingEnv
     10 import pandas as pd

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\env.py in <module>
      2 
      3 from os import environ
----> 4 from urlparse import urlparse as _urlparse
      5 
      6 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) was its own built-in (i.e., NOT `pip`-installable) module in Python 2, and was moved to `urllib.parse` (also in the standard lib) in Python 3. For some reason the `env` package that you have installed is still referring to the old location. That needs to be updated with the new module. You can edit it directly, see if a new version is available, or request an update to its source, depending on your time and abilities.

Comment: You're right! So I know for the future, which modules are common pitfalls that are python2 only?

Comment: @JimmyCarlos there were a lot of changes between Python 2 and 3, and new modules have been added in successive releases of Py3. Your best bet is to just google your errors and related modules. The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/index.html) are a great place to start.

Comment: I went into env.py at ~Anaconda3\lib\site-packages location and then changed the from urlparse import urlparse as _urlparse to  from urllib.parse import urljoin. Then I got another error. Then I restarted Jupytor Notebook, ran and gor the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'env.StockTradingEnv'; 'env' is not a package

Comment: I think now it is not even going into env.py !

Comment: @Kashan where did `env.py` come from? Is it something you set up yourself, or someone gave it to you, or is it part of the Anaconda distribution? I don't use Anaconda, so I don't know if it's standard or not.

Comment: @MattDMo I install it from Anaconda distribution using pip install.